# Getting "package R does not exist" when building from command-line

Tags: android, android-ndk, cocos2d-x

I created an activity on a separate project using Eclipse. When I imported it into my cocos2d-x android project and built the project using `python build_native.py` (which is basically building the app using the NDK) and `ant debug`, I get an error saying:

```
error: package R does not exist
```

pointing to the line:

```
setContentView(R.layout.some_activity);
                ^
```

I have added the `res/layout/some_activity.xml` in my cocos2d-x project as well as the manifest entries:

```
<application
    <!-- <application> tag info --> >
    <activity
        <!-- cocos2d-x native activity --> >
    </activity>

    <!-- the activity I imported -->
    <activity
        android:name="com.mycompany.myapp.SomeActivity"
        android:label="" 
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog"
        android:excludeFromRecents="true" 
        android:noHistory="true" 
    />
</application>
```

I also copied the needed `*.java` files inside the `src` folder (in the exact same folder structure).
I also tried cleaning manually (by deleting the `bin`, `gen`, `obj`, and `assets` folders) and through `ant clean`. I am not using Eclipse to build, only from the command-line.

**EDIT**: I also tried adding `import com.mycompany.myapp.R;` as well as `import com.mycompany.R;` on `SomeActivity.java` but it still didn't fix it.

How do I fix this error? Any other steps I am missing?

Comment: Probably there are some errors in your xml files. If so, the R.java can't be generated

Comment: Can you tell me some of the errors in XML? I'm pretty sure the syntax is correct. The only difference between the source project and the cocos2d-x project is that in the source project, the main activity and the `SomeActivity` is on the same package while on the cocos2d-x project, they are on different packages.

Comment: Eclipse can help you auto-detect syntax error

Comment: I made the activity in Eclipse (on a separate project) and when I was done with it, I imported it to my cocos2d-x project (where I don't use Eclipse), so I'm sure my XML have correct syntax.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had to import the cocos2d-x project's package name, not the imported activity's package name.

For example, if your cocos2d-x project's package name was `com.mycompany.cocosapp` and your imported activity's package name was `com.mycompany.myapp`, import `com.mycompany.cocosapp.R` instead of `com.mycompany.myapp.R`.

Answer (score 0):

Delete the bin folder and  rebuild the bin folder you need build it using ant and then run it.